# Is the output mixed like this because of xargs and how can I fix it?

Tags: scripting, xargs, output

I'm learning a bit of [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) by using [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to list whois records for a bunch of IP addresses. The command used is:

```
echo "$1" | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 -n 1 -t -P 3 -I %  sh -c 'echo "\n 44rBegin whois record -- \n"; whois -h whois.arin.net % ; echo "\n 44rEnd whois record -- \n"'
```

The executed commands are:

```
sh -c echo "\n 44rBegin whois record -- \n"; whois -h whois.arin.net 206.190.36.45 ; echo "\n 44rEnd whois record -- \n"
sh -c echo "\n 44rBegin whois record -- \n"; whois -h whois.arin.net 212.146.69.237 ; echo "\n 44rEnd whois record -- \n"
sh -c echo "\n 44rBegin whois record -- \n"; whois -h whois.arin.net 77.238.184.24 ; echo "\n 44rEnd whois record -- \n"
```

I want the output to appear as if each block of commands executed using `sh -c` is executed sequentially. Instead my output is something like:

```
44rBegin whois record

44rBegin whois record

44rBegin whois record

whois1 output

44rEnd whois record --

whois2 output

44rEnd whois record --

whois3 output

44rEnd whois record --
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you have multiple processes outputting to the same terminal (or file) in parallel, you run the risk of their output getting interspersed (unless you arrange to do some sort of locking or use low-level system calls like `write` to files opened in append-only mode).

As a first step, you can minimize, but not totally eliminate, the problem by having each shell invocation use [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03): run the `whois` command as a subprocess, capturing its output, then output everything combined into one `printf` operation.

```
xargs -0 -n 1 -P 3 -I %% sh -c 'printf "\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" " 44rBegin whois record -- " "$(whois -h whois.arin.net %%)" " 44rEnd whois record -- "'
```

Even better, if you have the `flock` program available, you can use it to lock each call to that combined `printf`:

```
xargs -0 -n 1 -P 3 -I %% sh -c 'who="$(whois -h whois.arin.net %%)"; flock /tmp/who.lock printf "\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" " 44rBegin whois record -- " "$who" " 44rEnd whois record -- "'
```

Comment: I was going to amend my answer to include this. This is a good idea, but from playing around the shell behaves really weird here. It'll output the first 4k bytes in a single `write()` operation, but after that it starts going line-by-line. Still, better than nothing at all though.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks, I forgot how big those whois records can be. I added a solution that uses `flock`.

Answer (score 6):

In this specific case, you're passing `-P 3` to `xargs`.

```
   -P max-procs
          Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs  is
          0,  xargs  will run as many processes as possible at a time.  Use the -n op‐
          tion with -P; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be done.
```

Because you're running them in parallel, the're all going to write their output at the same time.

If you copied this command from somewhere else, I would recommend that you research to understand what it is you're copying. Doing otherwise can be dangerous.

Comment: the command is not copied.  THe idea was that if I  have n=100 P=3 ( or anumber close to that) would make the whole batch execution  faster. At least from what i understand. And how can i make that whole block (echo; whois;echo) inseparable but the sh parallel?

Comment: It's called locking and it's really hard in sh. I find it much easier to spool to specific files and then cat them later.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the output is mixed because of `xargs -P`. You're executing several subprocesses in parallel, and there is nothing to coordinate their output: they're all writing output whenever they want and it all gets mixed up.

Use [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which is a far more powerful tool to do the same job as `xargs -P`. Its default is to [group output from each job together](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#group).

```
echo "$1" | parallel -t -P 3 sh -c 'echo "\n 44rBegin whois record -- \n"; whois -h whois.arin.net $0; echo "\n 44rEnd whois record -- \n"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell parallelism tools are less than a dime a dozen.  I've personally written 3 of them.  The most recent one is at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/coordinate/ .  It can be checked out and installed with:

```
svn checkout http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/coordinate/trunk/ coordinate && cd coordinate && make install
```

You can get one file per IP address with:

```
coord-xargs-like \
        -0 \
        --max-args 1 \
        whois -h whois.arin.net \
    | coordinate \
        --use-threads \
        --commands-file /dev/stdin \
    | coord-to-files --to-stdout --directory results/.
```

It'll default to using concurrency equal to the number of CPU cores your system has (including hyperthreads).

You get running updates of what is being output, as the commands are run, *and* one file per command in the results directory. The output isn't jumbled because coordinate uses a lock.

Note that I've left out the result framing.  With one file per whois, you no longer need it.

Further note that with one result file per command, you can use tools like equivs3e to quickly and conveniently eliminate duplicates as you're sifting through the output:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/equivalence-classes.html

```
find results/ -type f -print0 | equivs3e -0 --delete-newer
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this problem?

Redirect stdout to a file for each process and `cat` all of them later, to demo this technique:

```bsh
seq 100 | sort -R |
  xargs -I@ -P0 sh -c '{ echo begin @ && sleep 0.@ && echo end @; } > $$.log' &&
  find . -name '*.log' -exec cat {} \+
```

To apply this technique to your command:

```bsh
echo "$1" |
  tr "\n" "\0" |
  xargs -0 -n 1 -t -P 3 -I % sh -c '{echo "\n 44rBegin whois record -- \n"; whois -h whois.arin.net % ; echo "\n 44rEnd whois record -- \n";} > $$.log' &&
  find . -name '*.log' -exec cat {} \+
```